# check if a hiddenfield contains more text other than commas with regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i need to create an asp.net validator control that will only allow a page to post if a hiddenfield is not empty and doesnt just contain commas.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnProductListTip" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must have at least one product selected against your tip" ControlToValidate="hdnProductListTip"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What is the expression i need to use in the validator?

Comment: hmmmm looks like i cannot use a validator against a hiddenfield

Answer (score 0):

> I think, you cannot use it using Regular Expression. Use Javascript for the same on Button ClientClick event.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckHiddenField() {
        debugger;
        var ID = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        Trim(ID);
        if (ID.value == '')
            return false;
        if (ID.value.indexOf(',') > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function Trim(ID) {
        LeftTrim(ID);
        RightTrim(ID);
    }
    function LeftTrim(Obj) {
        var Trim = new RegExp('^\\s*');
        Obj.value = Obj.value.replace(Trim, '');
    }
    function RightTrim(obj) {
        var Trim = new RegExp('\\s*$');
        obj.value = obj.value.replace(Trim, '');
    }
</script>
```